# joint problem during workout

Tags: workout, joints, soreness

I can heard a little snap in my shoulder every time I do a jumping jack.
Can hear it sometimes when i do military press to.

It's not hurting on the moment, but afterward I have a little soreness where the snap seems to come from.

Samething in my leg (knee) when i do squat.

I tend to get a good streching before working out, someone have a solution/explanation for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually during and after exercise varieties of sounds comes out from joints no need to worry about that so much if u are not feeling pain. Soreness usually happens if the person is not usually habituated to the exercise. I means to say that if u r doing 10 reps of military press a day with other exercises and u suddenly increase it to 25 or 30 then this type of soreness happens.

Bruce lee said it best that u should do reps slowly and in many courses of such reps with rest (of at least 10 seconds) between each courses.

relaxation is as much important as exercises.

So, if u r increasing these things try slowly day by day.

Also eat good and sleep well :-)